# Microsoft Outlook: Redirect Emails to Address Based On Recipient

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, outlook-web-access

At my organization, we have 2 domains, example.com and example.net. We use Microsoft Exchange and Outlook to organize our email on example.com; however, we do not have email set up with example.net. Anything sent to @example.net gets redirected to a specific email address on example.com. It's a constant problem that people keep sending emails to @example.net, but the intended recipient does not receive the email. Right now, we just manually forward the @example.net email to the approprate @example.com address. I want to know if it's possible to automate this.

**Example:** Emails sent to **burkybang@example.net** redirect to **burkybang@example.com**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set up Exchange so each **example.net** email is sent to the relevant **example.com** recipient.

- Add example.net as an accepted domain
- Set up an email address policy so each user is assigned an `<alias>@example.com` address and an `<alias>@example.net` address. Set the example.com addresses as the reply addresses.[image: screenshot]
- For each mailbox user, under the Email Addresses section, tick 'Automatically update email addresses based on email address policy'

Each user will then automatically be given an example.com and example.net address. Their emails will be sent from example.com.